# Monitor the executors of Spark Application

Tags: apache-spark

Who is responsible to monitor the executors of Spark Application ?

1. Driver Node
2. Worker Node

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean failures, but not entirely sure. But in a general sense:

- The Spark DAG Scheduler and the corresponding supporting Cluster Manager (YARN StandAlone, et al) APIs and what not, will handle failed Executor Situations will ensure that Executor failures are handled via re-scheduling up until a maximum amount of times.
- Executors report a heartbeat and partial metrics for active Tasks to HeartbeatReceiver on the Driver. That is monitored by the Driver.
- If a Node is lost, Spark will request resources - as it did initially when program initiates - from the Cluster Manager.
- No such thing for the Driver, it is a single point of failure. If it dies, the whole Spark App dies as well.

Good link:
[https://data-flair.training/blogs/how-apache-spark-works/#:~:text=The%20individual%20task%20in%20the,application%20can%20continue%20with%20ease](https://data-flair.training/blogs/how-apache-spark-works/#:%7E:text=The%20individual%20task%20in%20the,application%20can%20continue%20with%20ease).